# How to compare strings in python in List?

Tags: python, list

I have recently started working wth Python. I need to compare strings in Python in the List and I am not sure how this will work out -

Below is my code -

```
def my_func ( event ):
  print event
  print (event.type)
  if event.type == EventType.CHILD:
    children=zk.get_children("/ss/testing", watch=my_func)
    print(children)
```

`print(children1)` will print out something like this, if it has one children or two or three-

```
[u'test1']

or

[u'test1', u'test2']

or

[u'test1', u'test2', u'test3']
```

I need to check whether `children` contains `workflow` string or not. Right now it only contains `test1, test2, test3` but in future it can have workflow as well like `test1, test2, test3, workflow`

If it contains `workflow`. Then I will print out only `workflow` and nothing else.

**NOTE:- get_children returns List as shown in the documentation I guess**

Any idea how this can be done?

**UPDATE:-**

If workflow nodes gets added up then it will show like this if I print out children-

```
[u'test1', u'test2', u'test3', u'workflow']
```

So I need to check whether children contains workflow or not, if it doesn't contains, then we won't do anything but if it contains, then we will print out workflow only not test1, test2, test3 after extracting from it.

Comment: Is workflow a string?

Comment: `"workflow" in children` should work ,., did you even try googling this first?

Comment: @DylanLawrence: I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I am not sure I understand what you said about "workflow" in children should work? btw, I have updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'workflow' in children
```

returns `True/False` if it is/isn't in children

Then, your code would be:

```
if 'workflow' in children: print 'workflow'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an in line `if` statement.

```
print('workflow' if 'workflow' in children else children)
```

Comment: That's not an inline `if-else`, it's called the `ternary conditional operator`.

Comment: Not to get bogged down in a symantic debate, but it is referred to as an in line if statement commonly (google it), and it is also an accurate description of it.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/ I find the word `ternary` , `conditional` and `operator` but no `inline`. I guess `inline if-else` must be just colloquial for what I was saying.